# Can't be parsed as format error from Luxon

Tags: javascript, web-deployment, luxon

I have a date `02/03/2022 0600` I'm trying to make a Luxon object like so

`` DateTime.fromFormat(`${date} ${time}`, 'MM/dd/yyy HHmm'), `` this results in an error `the input "02/03/2022 0600" can't be parsed as format MM/dd/yyy hhmm`

It works fine with dates and times separately with the same format. Is Luxon unable to parse dates and times together in this way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have missed a y in `'MM/dd/yyy HHmm'`. Change it to `'MM/dd/yyyy HHmm'`

```js
let a = luxon.DateTime.fromFormat('02/03/2022 0600', 'MM/dd/yyyy HHmm')
 
 console.log(a)
 
 console.log(Object.entries(a))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.3.0/luxon.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: omg i'm so sorry